# Best way to create a hashmap in ES6 with number as index

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to build an hashmap class, or use one that comes with the language.

The index are integers. 
If I try to do this with an array, I see on the debugger than the size of the array is equals to the higher integer key.

Ie, if my hashmap has two elements,  `Map[0]= 'word1'` and `Map[1023]= 'word2'` I can see that the array has size 1024.
I'd prefer not to waste so much space.

I can't make any assumption on how the keys are distributed.

Comment: `var blah = {}` (don't use `var Map` ... Map is a [thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in browsers except early internet exploders < 11)

Comment: No, the size is still 1023.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. A js object doesn't have a length

Comment: *"I'd prefer not to waste so much space."* Arrays in JavaScript work differently than in other languages. They are basically just objects. An array that has `length` 1000 doesn't necessarily take up that much space.

Comment: Correct, but you are not taking advantage of new ES6 browser implementations.  An array is probably implemented with a linked list and a hashmap, but we don't have control on the pre allocated size.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 introduces a true [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type which can be used as follows:

```
const m = new Map();
m.set(0, "word1");
m.set(1023, "word2");
for(const [key, value] of m) {
    console.log(key, value, typeof key);
}
```

Note how `key` is still a number - using an object literal, keys are always strings. It also provides a `size` property for counting key/value pairs:

```
const m = new Map();
m.set(0, "word1");
m.set(1023, "word2");
console.log(m.size); // 2
```

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20%20%20%20let%20m%20%3D%20new%20Map()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20m.set(0%2C%20%22word1%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20m.set(1023%2C%20%22word2%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for(const%20%5Bkey%2C%20value%5D%20of%20m)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(key%2C%20value%2C%20typeof%20key)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20m%20%3D%20new%20Map()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20m.set(0%2C%20%22word1%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20m.set(1023%2C%20%22word2%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(m.size)%3B%20%2F%2F%202)